# How Batch File will wait for Java application finish running first before calling other function

Tags: java, batch-file, wait

In Batch file if I want to wait for the exe program to finish before call other exe or function I use

```
start /WAIT application.exe
```

I have a Java application I run.

```
Java -cp "path" applicationName
```

is there a way batch file can wait for this application to finish first before it continues calling other functions same as the /WAIT option

thank you in advance

Comment: Console programs should cause a wait.  GUI programs (usually started with `javaw`) typically won't.

Comment: it is not a GUI program how to make sure it is console java program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put Java -cp "path" applicationName in a separate batch file, say, applicationName.bat, then use `call applicationName.bat` from your main batch.